# Convergence of a product of polynomials

Tags: polynomials, convergence-divergence

Let $m$ be a positive integer, and define $f_n\colon[0,1]\to[0,1]$ recursively as follows:
$$f_0(x)=(1-x)^m.$$
$$f_{n+1}(x)=f_n(x)\cdot(1-x^k)\qquad\text{if }f_n(x)-1+mx\in\Theta(x^k).$$
I am pretty sure that this converges to $f(x)=\max\{1-mx,0\}$. In fact, if we write
$$
f_n(x)=1-mx+ax^k+O(x^{k+1})\text{ with }a\ne0,
$$
then $f_{n+1}(x)=1-mx+(a-1)x^k+O(x^{k+1})$ so that the coefficient $a$ gets consumed step by step until it is zero and then the next power is attacked. However, this would require that the integer $a$ is never negative. According to numerical experiments, this indeed seems to be the case, but I don't see a compelling argument for this.
I tried to show that $f_n\ge f$ or that $f_n(\frac1m)\to 0$, but ended up running in circles.

**Q:** Can anyone prove (or disprove) that $f_n\to f$ and in particular that the first non-zero coefficient $a$ above is always positive?

---

Here are the first terms of the sequence for $m=2$:
$$\begin{align}
f_0(x)=(1-x)^2&=1-2x+x^{\color{red}2}\\
f_1(x)=f_0(x)(1-x^{\color{red}2})&=1-2x+2x^{\color{red}3}-x^4\\
f_2(x)=f_1(x)(1-x^{\color{red}3})&=1-2x+x^{\color{red}3}+x^4-2x^6+x^7\\
f_3(x)=f_2(x)(1-x^{\color{red}3})&=1-2x+3x^{\color{red}4}-3x^6+2x^9-x^{10}\\
f_4(x)=f_3(x)(1-x^{\color{red}4})&=1-2x+2x^{\color{red}4}+2x^5-3x^6+\cdots\\
f_5(x)=f_4(x)(1-x^{\color{red}4})&=\cdots
\end{align}$$
And here's a plot of
$$\begin{align}f_{69}(x)=&(1-x)^2(1-x^2)(1-x^3)^2\cdot\\& (1-x^4)^3(1-x^5)^6(1-x^6)^9\cdot\\&(1-x^7)^{18}(1-x^8)^{30}\end{align} $$

[image]

(So apparently, for $m=2$, there is a relation to [A001037](http://oeis.org/A001037) or [A059966](http://oeis.org/A059966) or [A060477](http://oeis.org/A060477))

Comment: Hopefully my edit preserves the intent of your question. Is it really the case that we multiply by the same factor $(1-x^k)$ at every step? If that's the case, then $f_n(0)$ is always $1$ but otherwise $f_n(x)\to0$ for all $x>0$.

Comment: @GregMartin No. $k$ is determined by the first non-zero coefficient after the linear one, which may change in each step

Comment: @GregMartin I added an example for clarification

Comment: Excellent clarifications, nicely done

Comment: Another way of writing the recursion: given $m$, let $g_0(x)=(1-x)^m$, define $c(i)$ to be the coefficient of $x^{i+1}$ in $g_{i-1}(x)$, and define $g_i(x) = g_{i-1}(x) (1-x^{i+1})^{c(i)}$.

Comment: For $m=2$, the sequence of exponents (that begins $1,2,3,6,9,18,30$ in your example) can be found in [three different forms on the OEIS](https://oeis.org/search?q=1%2C2%2C3%2C6%2C9%2C18%2C30%2C56%2C99%2C186%2C335%2C630%2C1161%2C2182%2C4080&sort=&language=english&go=Search). Perhaps that will lead to some understanding, since identifying these exponents seems crucial for proving the desired limit.

Comment: @GregMartin Yes, that is a nice shortcut and could even be performed with negative $c(i)$. The main question remains the same: Will $c(i)$ always be non-negative and thus will $g_i$ always be a apolynomial? (And of course: will $g_i\to f$?)

Comment: @GregMartin In PARI, `F(d,n)=A=vector(n-2,x,0);P=(1-x)^d+O(x^n);for(k=2,n-1,c=polcoeff(P,k);A[k-1]=c;P*=(1-x^k+O(x^n))^c);A` can give us these exponent sequences. The OEIS hits point to: number of irreducible polynomials in $\Bbb F_d$ (of course only for prime power $d$); dimensions of free Lie algebras; and number of aperiodic necklaces of beads in $d$ colours. The latter seems most promising in this context ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apparently, I stumbled over the [cyclotomic identity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cyclotomic_identity)
$${1 \over 1-\alpha z}=\prod_{j=1}^\infty\left({1 \over 1-z^j}\right)^{M(\alpha,j)} $$ of (formal) power series
where the detail that matters is that $M(\alpha,j)$ is a non-negative integer because it *counts* something.

Taking reciprocals and renaming variables as in my question, we get
$$\tag2 1-dx=(1-x)^d\cdot \prod_{k=2}^\infty(1-x^k)^{a_k}$$
where the $a_k$ are non-negative integers. While this equality seems absurd when $\frac1d<x\le 1$, when the left hand side is negative and the right hand side is a product of non-negative numbers, keep in mind that an infinite product does not converge when the partial product of all non-zero factors converges to $0$ or when infinitely many of the factors are $=0$. Hence $(2)$ makes a statement about the sequence of partial products only for $0\le x<\frac1d$, whereas the partial product then necessarily converges point-wise to $0$ for $\frac1d\le x\le 1$.
If we consider such a partial product, then none of the later factors can change the low order terms of the power series so that
$$ (1-x)^d\prod_{k=1}^m(a-x^k)^{a_k}=1-dx+O(x^{m+1}). $$
This also means that
$$ (1-x)^d\prod_{k=1}^{m-1}(a-x^k)^{a_k}=1-dx+a_mx^m+O(x^{m+1}).$$
Going backwards, we conclude that the recursion defined in the OP will indeed use multiplication by $(1-x^k)$ in exactly $a_k\in\Bbb N_0$ steps, and also that $f_n\to f$ as conjectured.